# How to stop thread if another thread has acquired lock on critical section?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have created a scheduler which executes a piece of program in x minutes time interval. If program execution takes more time, next job should not wait for the current job to get completed. I am using `System.Timers.Timer`.

```
_scheduler = new System.Timers.Timer(SomeMinutes);
_scheduler.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
_scheduler.Enabled = true;
_scheduler.AutoReset = true;

private void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
   lock(obj)
   {
     //Critical Section
   }
}
```

if i use lock, next thread waits for current thread to release lock. i don't want this behavior. if a thread acquired lock object on critical section then another thread should exit without executing critical section

Comment: I would have thought specifying a timeout such as `cs.Lock(timeout)` would have done the trick?

Comment: I don't get cs.Lock(timeout). What is cs object?

Comment: Sorry actually you would need to use [Monitor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.monitor(v=vs.110).aspx) since .NET doesn't wrap the OS critical section the way it does for `Mutex`.  Specifically [Monitor.TryEnter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/42h9d380(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Monitor`.

MSDN:

> The Monitor class controls access to objects by granting a lock for an object to a single thread. Object locks provide the ability to restrict access to a block of code, commonly called a critical section. While a thread owns the lock for an object, no other thread can acquire that lock. You can also use Monitor class to ensure that no other thread is allowed to access a section of application code being executed by the lock owner, unless the other thread is executing the code using a different locked object.  [More please...](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Threading.Monitor(v=vs.110).aspx)

But you might ask, *"isn't that what c#'s `lock()` does?"* and in some ways yes.  However the really nice thing about `Monitor` is that you can attempt to get a lock and **specify a timeout** to wait rather than blocking the thread until possibly the end of time or at least until you have finished reading that copy of *War and Peace*.

Plus unlike `Mutex`, `Monitor`s are light-weight to use! Just like critical sections in the deep plumbings of Windows OS.

Change your code from

```
private void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
   lock(obj)
   {
     //Critical Section
   }
}
```

...to:

```
object _locker = new object();
const int SomeTimeout=1000;

private void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    if (!Monitor.TryEnter(_locker, SomeTimeout))
    {
        throw new TimeoutException("Oh darn");
    }

    try
    {
        // we have the lock so do something
    }
    finally
    {
        // must ensure to release the lock safely
        Monitor.Exit(_locker);
    }   
}
```

Here's what MSDN has to say about `TryEnter`:

> Attempts, for the specified number of milliseconds, to acquire an exclusive lock on the specified object - [Tell me more...](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/42h9d380(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Try below:

```
 ThreadPoolScheduler.Instance.Schedule(
    TimeSpan.FromSeconds(SomeSecondsSuchAs30), () => doNotWaitAnyMore());
```

Since you are working on task scheduling jobs, [ThreadPoolScheduler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reactive.concurrency.threadpoolscheduler%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) deserves a closer look.

Alternatively you can use [Polly](https://github.com/michael-wolfenden/Polly), which might save you hours:

```
Policy.Handle<TimeoutException>().Execute(() => {
    //Logic for no longer waiting current job, .e.g start a new job
    doNotWaitAnyMore();
});
```

And in your long lasting job, throw a [TimeoutException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timeoutexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). That is it!

Comment: I don't want to set timeout SomeSecondsSuchAs30. It is magic number right. i have no idea what value to set. i am expecting .net native library to achieve this so i can't use Polly